# Operator overloading returning a reference

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I am trying to understand what is the real deal with returning a reference, while studying operator overloading. I create this very simple problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class mydoub {
    public:
        double pub;
        mydoub(double i = 0) : pub(i) {}
};

mydoub &operator += (mydoub &a, double b) {
    a.pub = a.pub+b;
    return a;
}


int main() {
    mydoub a(5), b(6);
    cout << "1: " << a.pub << "  " << b.pub << endl; // expected output 1: 5 6
    b = a+= 7;
    cout << "2: " << a.pub << "  " << b.pub << endl; // expected output 2: 12 12
    b.pub = 8;
    cout << "3: " << a.pub << "  " << b.pub << endl; // unexpected output: 3: 12  8
}
```

The output is:

```
1: 5  6
2: 12  12
3: 12  8
```

which is quite unexpected to me. In fact, `b` has been assigned a reference to `a`, right after the latter has been modified, so I expect `b.pub=8` to act on `a` as well, as a result of the reference passing through the operator `+=`. Why isn't it so? What is then the difference with a non-reference overload, say `mydoub operator += ( ..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing with an understanding of reference. Reference, in fact, is just dereferenced pointer and when you do `b = a`, it is actually copying the a value to b, they are not pointing to the same object. To point to the same object you need to use pointers or make b not mydoub type, but mydoub& type (in that case, while initializing you can point to the same object).

mydoub& operator += is used to can modify the result of += operator. For example,

```cpp
mydoub a = 1;
++(a += 3)
```

After that a will 5, but if you use mydoub operator += it will be 4.

Comment: so, are you saying that passing by reference is equivalent to provide some sort of temporary pointer to what I am returning, but just within the scope of the return statement?

Comment: It just returns the equivalent of the temporary pointer but dereferenced. As a result, references cannot be null.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I think I know what you mean now, and it all makes sense to me